# dbfpy returning int() error on str

Tags: python, excel, dbf

I have a pile of dbfs that I am trying to churn into xls.

Things are good and great on my test files of various examples, but when applied to the big nasty files at work (with "real world" examples) my code returns:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\...\final_sum _sw.py", line 73, in <module>
        dbf_xls(z, output_xls) #defined, reads dbf, writes xls
      File "C:\...\final_sum _sw.py", line 18, in dbf_xls
        sheet1.row(row).write(col, DBF[row][col])
      File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\dbfpy\dbf.py", line 242, in __getitem__
        return self.RecordClass.fromStream(self, self._fixIndex(index))
      File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\dbfpy\record.py", line 121, in fromStream
        return cls.fromString(dbf, cls.rawFromStream(dbf, index), index)
      File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\dbfpy\record.py", line 140, in fromString
        [_fd.decodeFromRecord(string) for _fd in dbf.header.fields])
      File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\dbfpy\fields.py", line 173, in decodeFromRecord
        return self.decodeValue(self.rawFromRecord(record))
      File "C:\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\site-packages\dbfpy\fields.py", line 244, in decodeValue
        return int(value)
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 U'
```

The offending value in the table = Cumula. Area is 1.1  Unknown material type.

Other files have the same problem returning the same 'number, space, letter' format or error.

dbfpy reads this field as 'c', but is there something about the decimals, periods that are causing dbfpy to treat this value as a int()?  Would there be anyway to force, trick the module into treating all values as strictly string values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that all the fields that gave me problems where long text fields (char length 253-256) that contained non-ascii characters (degree symbols, other weird things that people decided to take the time to insert).
Solution:

```
import codecs
blah_blah.encode("ascii", "ignore")
```

I may have replaced errors with ?'s, or something of the like.

Comment: This does not look like real answer? How shall `blah_blah.encode` affect reading from dbf file? This seems to be different problem with printing contained strings out, but not with reading.

Comment: your_string_variable_name.encode("ascii", "ignore") better?

Comment: the problem is in this call `sheet1.row(row).write(col, DBF[row][col])`, in fact it is just the `DBF[row][col]`. Whatever following this call is inside of `dbf` library, which you cannot influence. I see no relation between this line and the answer, which seems to resolve problem of another type (problems to encode some string to encoding of your console or whatever it goes to).

Answer (score 0):

I have not used `dbfpy`.  Have you tried using [my dbf module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf)?  The code would look something like:

```
import dbf
table = dbf.Table(r'\path\to\dbf_file\filename')
table.open()
```

and later:

```
for row, record in enumerate(table):
    for col, value in enumerate(record):
        sheet1.row(row).write(col, value)
```

If you have any problems feel free to contact me via email.